# Json Request with POSTMAN

Tags: java, json

I have this class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
IntestatarioPrivacySospensiva {
    private IntestatarioInput intestatario;
    private List<DatiPrivacySospensiva> datiPrivacy;
    private String sportelloRiferimento;
    private String riferimento;
    private String note;
    private String accettazioneConsensoC1;
    private String accettazioneConsensoC3;
}
```

I have to make a JSON request to map this object, I have made this but it is never seen as `IntestatarioPrivacySospensiva` object.

```
[
{
//this are intestatarioInput variable   
    "abi":"abi",
    "cf":"cf",
    "ndg":"ndg"
},
    {//This are datiprivacy variable
        "tipoConsenso":"tipoConsenso",
        "consenso":"consenso"
    },
    {
        "sportelloRiferimento":"sportelloRif",
        "riferimento":"riferimento",
        "note":"note",
        "accettazioneConsensoC1":"true",
        "accettazioneConsensoC3":"false"
    }
]
```

My service have in the request ArrayList x; how i have to map it in json?
I'm using Postman to send JSON.

Comment: Please provide the relevant code of your service. Are you sure is `IntestatarioPrivacySospensiva` class what you're serializing into a JSON to return as the service response?

Comment: the problem is not in the service..i need to map the json in postman body request.

Comment: The question is not clear enough. Are you using a library to map JSON to Java classes? Are you trying to create an instance of `IntestatarioPrivacySospensiva` from a JSON and you need to know how to format the JSON?

Comment: yes i need to create an instance from a JSON

Comment: Ok, sorry for misunderstanding. Then your main issue is how JSON works. For starters, an object in JSON is defined using braces `{}`  not brackets `[]`. What you have defined is an array of objects.

Comment: Just to be sure: are you using Postman to send a JSON to your Java service which will end up creating an instance of  `IntestatarioPrivacySospensiva`? If this is the case, we need to know something about the service, otherwise this question will never get a useful response.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work:

```
[{
  "sportelloRiferimento":"sportelloRif",
  "riferimento":"riferimento",
  "note":"note",
  "accettazioneConsensoC1":"true",
  "accettazioneConsensoC3":"false",
  "intestatario" : {
    "abi":"abi",
    "cf":"cf",
    "ndg":"ndg"
  },
  "datiPrivacy" : [ {
    "tipoConsenso":"tipoConsenso",
        "consenso":"consenso"
  } ]
},
{
  "sportelloRiferimento":"sportelloRif",
  "riferimento":"riferimento",
  "note":"note",
  "accettazioneConsensoC1":"true",
  "accettazioneConsensoC3":"false",
  "intestatario" : {
    "abi":"abi",
    "cf":"cf",
    "ndg":"ndg"
  },
  "datiPrivacy" : [ {
    "tipoConsenso":"tipoConsenso",
        "consenso":"consenso"
  } ]
}]
```

You can use Jackson 2.x to get JSON strings from your Java objects. Checkout the below example:

> https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Comment: Updated the answer for List<IntestatarioPrivacySospensiva>